# Screen to World transform

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, 2d

I have a x,y position in screen coordinates. I know the camera position, orientation vector and fov angle. I want a vector in the direction of the x,y position, like in ray tracing. So the vector would intersect with the 3d world object that is in the screen x,y position.

It's not in a graphical library, the camera is a real world camera, so I would need the inverse of what a GL normally does.

What tools are in .net to achieve this? Like a transformation matrix that can be created automatically giving the camera information (position, orientation, fov, etc), and would transform a 2D point to a 3DVector.

Thanks